# What can prevent a Server 2008 machine accessing its OWN UNC shares?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, unc

I need to set up a UNC share for my hosted dedicated server to access a share on itself. Unfortunately TFS requires a UNC share.

I am on a `Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 64bit` dedicated server behind a PIX 501 firewall hosted with GoDaddy.

I just cannot get the server to access itself and get this error:

> Windows cannot access `\\SERVER\SHARE`
>   Check the spelling of the name.. etc.

I've found [numerous questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/32650/windows-2008-server-cannot-access-any-network-share/131892#131892) about this but no answer to my problem.

- Server 2008 Standard x64 SP2
- Workgroup - not domain
- Windows Firewall is off
- Computer browser service is on
- I am trying to access `\\MYMACHINE\TFS-BUILDS` by typing in - or double clicking. Neither works.
- Machine has single network card
- Filesharing wizard says share was ok
- Share was showing under 'Computer management'
- Permissions are set to 'everyone' full control
- No obvious errors in eventlog
- Reboot didn't fix it
- Unfortunately I cannot try to access other shares in or out of this machine because it is a hosted dedicated server and the only machine behind a hardware firewall.

The only thing left i can think of is that the hardware firewall needs to be configured. I don't think it is this because we have a 2003 Server machine behind a different hardware firewall and that one works fine.

What on earth is left?!

Comment: What happens if you try to access the machine via it's IP address?

Comment: @ben doesn't work :(. also tried adding hostname to my hosts file

Comment: found this monster list of sharing issues. not found an answer yet. http://kadaitcha.cx/file_sharing.html

Answer (score 4):

OK I got it!

Apparently 'File and printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks' is not installed for the network adapter by default.
I'm not sure if this is a Windows 2008 default or the network card's default.

Here's what fixed it:

- Right click on 'Local Area Connection'
- Verify that 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks' is NOT there
- Assuming you don't see it - Click 'Install'
- Double click on 'Service'
- Select 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks'
- Click OK to install it
- Reboot machine

You should be able to see it now. Jees! (Answer from http://kadaitcha.cx/file_sharing.html)

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm having the same problem with every one of our new Server 2008 systems and all of them have the 'File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks' binding enabled on their only NIC. I can access the same share from another location, just can't access a share on the system I'm currently on. Which is too bad, because I use that trick to create Run-From-Anywhere shortcuts.

Comment: Best answer and to the point. I was going nuts from last 2 hours.

Comment: @MandeepJanjua best answer! I'm flattered :-) (even though all answers on this question are mine)

Comment: @Simon I meant to say this is the best answer from all of your answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

When trying to access administrative shares such as `\\servername\c$` you may need to set a registry key - yes really!

This is what Microsoft calls '[UAC remote restrictions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016)'

```
> Key:
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
> Value: LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy 
> Data: 1 (to disable, 0 enables filtering)
> Type: REG_DWORD (32-bit)
```

See http://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/08/access-denied-trying-to-connect-to-administrative-shares-on-windows-7/

Comment: (this was on Windows 2012 Server)

Answer (score 0):

It is an old thread, but just in case it can help someone:

Even the "File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks" service and "Client for Microsoft Networks" client were already installed, I had to uninstall and install them again, restarting each time. That solved it for me!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was unable to do a self-network share:
`dir \\HOSTNAME\c$`

Nor in Explorer:
`\\HOSTNAME\c$`

The final solution was to turn on IPV6.

1. Open *Network and Sharing Center* -> Local Area Connection
2. Right-Click and select *Properties*
3. Select *Internet Protocol Version 6*

Also make sure you have *File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks* installed and enabled.