# Server cannot access its OWN UNC path share

Tags: windows-server-2012, unc

I have some trouble with a Windows 2012 server(lets assume  server name **SERVER1**)

Using administrator account (Domain Admin), this server cannot access `\\SERVER1\C$` or its IP `\\10.10.10.1\C$`. error occurs with `DIR` command, `Get-ChildItem` and Windows Explorer.

The UNC path is also inaccessible through network too.

Sometime `DIR \\10.10.10.1\C$` or using `PowerShell` or `Explorer` works perfectly and sometime `error 53` is thrown

I, by the way, checked on Microsoft forum and this thread [What can prevent a Server 2008 machine accessing its OWN UNC shares?](https://serverfault.com/questions/131898/what-can-prevent-a-server-2008-machine-accessing-its-own-unc-shares) and no luck so far

Any idea why? Or any lead?

Thanks

Comment: Does Domain Admins has admin rights on server?

Comment: Did you, why ever, disable the default administrative shares? Via registry or some other means?

Comment: Admin has full access on server and admin shares are enabled
Well share are sometimes available and sometime error 53 is showed even in local

Comment: Error 53 is thrown even if you use the IP? That's sketchy, sounds like your NetBIOS name resolution and / or DNS / TCP/IP connections are not established. Can you do a `ping -t 10.10.10.1` for some time and look at dropped packets? What's in the eventlog?

Comment: Are you loggen in interactive? Via RDP? Via Powershell remoting?

Comment: Does it happen if you try to access the server from a client too?

Comment: Slipper: Domain Admins have full rights
Lenniey: Admin shares are ON and enabled and no packets were dropped
restless1987: RDP & PS still same issue
MarcelJanus:Yes clients have same issue